# Animated GIF on Wordpress posts?

Tags: images, wordpress.com-hosting

We have included couple animated GIF images on our [blog post](http://wewanttolearn.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/koch-division/). They animate in the CMS but not on the post itself (unless you click on them). How can we animated them on the post? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Animated gifs will not be animated when resized. I see that you're using the full sized image, but there are parameters added to the src attribute (probably due to some plugin or your theme):

From the source:

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-4604" title="Koch snoflake progression" alt="" src="http://wewanttolearn.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/snowflake-diagrams1.gif?w=545&amp;h=472" height="472" width="545">
```

Take off the parameters `?w=545&amp;h=472`, and it should work. Leave the width and height attributes on the image, and it will still be displayed at 472x545. Tested it in Chrome dev tools, and it worked.

Fixed:

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-4604" title="Koch snowflake progression" alt="Koch snowflake progression" src="http://wewanttolearn.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/snowflake-diagrams1.gif" height="472" width="545">
```

Comment: Thanks @goto10 I just copy pasted the fixed code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No prob, we'll get it. That code should work though. I just tested again to be sure. Have you published the edit?. Looking at your link, I still see the old code: `<img class="size-full wp-image-4604" title="Koch snowflake progression" alt="Koch snowflake progression" src="http://wewanttolearn.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/snowflake-diagrams1.gif?w=545&amp;h=472" height="472" width="545">`

Comment: Hi goto10, I just published the mofified image with your fixed code but I am still not seeing the animation...

Comment: Hi Arthur. Okay, upon closer inspection, I see that you're site is using WordPress.com and not .org, which means this question is generally of out of scope for WPSE.  Anyway, looking at the page's source, the image still has the resize arguments on the src attribute. Can you switch over to the text editor and make sure those arguments are removed, then republish? The original gif is really big: 1365x1183. Another solution would be to resize the gif in some external program, so that it natively fits within the content area of your theme, which is a maximum width of 545 pixels.